# Nested TabActivities and Intent based Communication

Tags: android, android-intent, tabactivity

I have 2 nested tabactivities - TopTabActivity and EmbeddedTabActivity. I want to pass some information from TopTab Activity to EmbeddedTabActivity when OnTabChanged Event is triggered in TopTabActivity. Both activities are initialized in the beginning of the appln. 
The problem is when I use Intent to pass the information from TopTabActivity to the existing EmbeddedTabActivity using startActivity() functionality, it starts a new instance of the EmbeddedTabActivity. I dont wish to have this behaviour. My wish is to take some action in the existing instance of the EmebeddedTabActivity when Intent is sent from the TopTabActivity.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Broadcasts and Receivers, intro'd here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers

Basically you're TopTab would Broadcast an event that your EmbeddedTab is registered to receive. Thats the gist.

Comment: I 'll check out the link. Thank you for the reply.